# «Прошло обучение более 2000 детей». Или прошли?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, согласование, сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число

> 6 направлений подготовки, по которым **прошло**/**прошли** обучение более 2000
> детей.

Единственное или множественное число, как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Что выбрать, если "обучение" не сказуемое...

Есть тенденция к использованию единственного числа с большими числами. Чем больше число, тем лучше единственное. *Две тысячи* относится к большим, но оно не очень большое, так что возможны оба варианта, но единственное предпочтительнее.

С Грамоты.ру:
Согласование сказуемого со словами *тысяча, миллион, миллиард*
Сказуемое при словах *тысяча, миллион, миллиард* обычно принимает форму подлежащего (**единственное число**, женский или мужской род). *Тысяча человек каждый год отдыхает в этом санатории. Миллион тюльпанов посажен на клумбе.*
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo

Answer (score 1):

Это кусок предложения, вырванного из контекста, поэтому рассмотрим варианты.

**1.** Главное — особенный процесс обучения (обучение — подлежащее), тогда надо использовать возвратный глагол (производилось обучение) или краткое страдательное причастие (произведено обучение).
*Шесть направлений подготовки, по которым прозводилось обучение* (кого?) *более 2000 детей.*

**2.** Главное — учились дети, обучились, их много (более двух тысяч детей — подлежащее).
Вот тогда лучше все-таки использовать форму множественного числа сказуемого (прошли обучение).
Во-первых, это сразу отметает двоякость понимания (обучение — ср. род).
Во-вторых, каждый ребенок учился, конечно, в группе, но в силу своих возможностей, своих мозгов, своего таланта; то есть образование он получил свое собственное, персональное, а не групповое.
В третьих, в пользу множественного числа говорит статистика: *прошл**и** обучение более* — **40900** (в Нацкорпусе — 2), *прошл**о** обучение более* — **4420** (в Нацкорпусе — 0).

*Шесть направлений подготовки, по которым прошл**и** обучение более 2000 детей.*

В прошлом году в 87 учебных центрах **прошли обучение более** 30 тысяч руководителей и специалистов различных отраслей экономики. [Система координат (2002) // «Вечерняя Москва», 13.03.2002]

> **10.** При обозначении приблизительного количества (путем постановки числительного впереди существительного или путем вставки слов ***около, свыше, больше, меньше*** и т. п.) сказуемое может стоять как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа (второй способ согласования все чаще встречается в наше время...

**3.** Цифры до десяти в предложении обычно оформляются прописью (тем более что одно число уже имеется).

[Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20(%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).)

Answer (score 1):

Выбираем форму мн. числа: *6 направлений подготовки, по которым **прошли** обучение более 2000 детей.*

**Пояснение**

**Грамматика предложения имеет два варианта**: количественный оборот может быть подлежащим или дополнением. Это связано с тем, что для сочетания «более 2000 детей" совпадают формы И.п. и В.п.  Сравнить: Там более 2000 детей (И.п.). Я вижу более 2000 детей (В.п.)

1. **Оборот является дополнением:**

6 направлений подготовки, по которым **прошло** обучение (кого?) более 2000 детей.

2. **Оборот является подлежащим**: *6 направлений подготовки, по которым **прошло/прошли** обучение (кто?) более 2000 детей.*

Сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим **по правилу Розенталя**: §184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте) Пункт 10

*При обозначении приблизительного количества (путем постановки числительного впереди существительного или путем вставки слов **около, свыше, больше, меньше** и т.п.) сказуемое может стоять **как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа** (второй способ согласования все чаще встречается в наше время).*

Также можно ориентироваться на **активный характер** действия, что соответствует форме мн. числа.

Comment: А когда же единственное использовать? Никогда?

Comment: Лучше никогда.  Эта форма ведет к неоднозначному пониманию грамматики, что является стилистическим недочетом. Но грамматически она допускается.

Comment: *Здесь проехало более 2000 машин.* А здесь как? Двусмысленность часто не будет.

Comment: А что здесь сложного? Выбор ед. или мн. числа делаем по тексту.  Если важно общее количество, то ед. число. Вчера здесь проехало более 2000 машин.  Сравнить:  Более 2000 машин уже проехали (то есть часть машин).

Comment: Мало ли. Вдруг опять выбрали бы множественное.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что оба варианта допустимы.
Выбор зависит от того, на чем вы хотите сделать акцент: на обучении или на детях.

> 6 направлений подготовки, по которым прошло *(что?)* **обучение** более 2000
> детей.

> 6 направлений подготовки, по которым прошли обучение *(кто?)* **более 2000
> детей**.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138036/discussion-on-answer-by-ivan-olshansky----2000---).